# Problem in Dynamically adding dropdownlist in table (C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am doing a very simple task but i am stuck at one point. I want to create a simple page (ASP.NET with C#) which displays a button initially. When user clicks on the button then a dropdownlist should be added to the page dynamically. I am doing this through C#. My problem is that the list is added to the page first time but after that only page refreshes and no more list is added. I don't know whats going on. Here is my code:

Default.aspx

```
    <%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master"  AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
    <asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>Welcome to My Store!</h2>

    <table id="itempanel" runat="server"></table>
    <asp:Button ID="additem" Text="Add" OnClick="addElement" runat="server" />

    </asp:Content>
```

Default.aspx.cs

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void addElement(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HtmlTableRow tr=new HtmlTableRow();
    HtmlTableCell tc = new HtmlTableCell();
    DropDownList mylist = new DropDownList();
    ListItem myitem = new ListItem("Item1");
    mylist.Items.Add(myitem);
    myitem = new ListItem("Item2");
    mylist.Items.Add(myitem);
    myitem = new ListItem("Item3");
    mylist.Items.Add(myitem);
    tc.Controls.Add(mylist);
    tr.Cells.Add(tc);
    itempanel.Rows.Add(tr);
  }
}
```

Comment: you will need to recreate the control on every postback

Comment: thanks. how can i do that? Please provide me some sample code.

Answer (score 2):

Dynamically added controls need to be re added when the postback happens.

One simple way is putting the same code in Load event and setting

```
    if(postback)
        {
      //your control adding code goes here... so when it is postback load event will add                   

      the control again. Other way is add the control through another method... 

          }
```

Another thing... normally we add controls in Page lifecycle Pre_Init method. Read about that too.

### Update

I forget to mention that you can also save the state of your data in view state. You will have to recreate the control on postback no matter what but if the data was changed that can be retrieved back from viewstate if you have saved it there. How to do that, is shown below. 
http://chiragrdarji.wordpress.com/2009/05/20/maintain-viewstate-for-dynamic-controls-across-the-postback/

Answer (score 1):

You need to *study* the ASP.NET `page life cycle`. (Whenever a page is requested all the controls and page object will be instantiated). There are many ways to do so but I think the simplest way is the use of `JavaScript` or `jQuery`.

However you may achieve the result with existing code,

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if(ViewState["isButtonClicked"]!=null) 
   {
        AddDropDown();
   }
}

protected void addElement(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(ViewState["isButtonClicked"]==null)
     {
       AddDropDown();
     }
    ViewState["isButtonClicked"]="yes";

}

void AddDropDown()
{
    HtmlTableRow tr=new HtmlTableRow();
    HtmlTableCell tc = new HtmlTableCell();
    DropDownList mylist = new DropDownList();
    ListItem myitem = new ListItem("Item1");
    mylist.Items.Add(myitem);
    myitem = new ListItem("Item2");
    mylist.Items.Add(myitem);
    myitem = new ListItem("Item3");
    mylist.Items.Add(myitem);
    tc.Controls.Add(mylist);
    tr.Cells.Add(tc);
    itempanel.Rows.Add(tr);
}
```

Comment: hi thanks for your help. I tried it, now two lists are added but nothing happens when i click the button third time. Can you fix it?

Comment: @ Nida Sulheri - Sorry! I didn't get you. Take a look at code where a single DropDownList is added and like that way you can add one or more DropDownList. Isn't that?

Comment: You are not getting my point. I am saying that when user clicks on the Add button, a new dropdownlist should be added (infact appended) to the page remaining all previous lists as it is...
What i am experience is that only one dropdownlist adds and when i try to add second nothing happens!!!

Comment: @Nida Sulheri - and how do you add the second one? Have you wrote another method which adds a new dropdownlist. The way I suggest is not a good method beside this you have to use jQuery or JavaScript. Please read and understand the ASP.NET page lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!IsPostBack)
   {
       AddDropDown();
   }
}
```